# Finding Activity level of gender

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

```
Membership
mID     StartingDate    Name     Address     Gender      EndingDate
```

And

```
Circulation Info
ISBN    mID    DateOfBorrow    DateOfReturn    DateOfLoss
```

I am attempting to find the activity level of each genders, but as of right now I am not having ver much luck.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT Membership.Gender, [Circulation Info].mID, Membership.mID
FROM [Circulation Info] AS c INNER JOIN Membership AS m ON [Circulation Info].mID = Membership.mID
GROUP BY m.mID
HAVING Membership.Gender='F'
```

I receive a syntax error when I attempt to run this and it directs me to Circulation Info on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issue about the table aliases (when you alias a table, you must then use that alias rather than the table name to qualify the field names), I think you want a `Count()` function to give you "activity level".

Also note Access generally complains about any field expression in the `SELECT` clause which is not included in the `GROUP BY` and is not an aggregate expression (`Min()`, `Max()`, `Count()`, etc.).

I don't see why you should need both `c.mID` and  `m.mID` in the `SELECT` list; they should be the same in each row.  Also consider moving the criterion, `m.Gender='F'`, from the `HAVING` to a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT m.mID, Count(*) AS activity_level
FROM
    [Circulation Info] AS c
    INNER JOIN Membership AS m
    ON c.mID = m.mID
WHERE m.Gender='F'
GROUP BY m.mID;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have set an alias for tables, but then use table name prefixing column names instead of alias. Try this:

```
SELECT m.Gender, c.mID, m.mID
FROM [Circulation Info] AS c INNER JOIN Membership AS m ON c.mID = m.mID
GROUP BY m.mID
HAVING m.Gender='F';
```

Comment: Access will likely complain about `m.Gender` and `c.mID` in the `SELECT` clause because they are not included in the `GROUP BY` and are not aggregate expressions.  But I'm not sure either of those are needed in the `SELECT` ... move `m.Gender='F'` from `HAVING` to `WHERE`.  Seems the OP might also want a `Count(*)` expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I received a message saying that the I tried to executed query that does not include the specified expression 'Gender' as a part of an aggregate function

Comment: To avoid this error you should include m.Gender to GROUP BY or apply some aggregate function on m.Gender. Can you, please, explain what kind of output do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

You are using aliases for the tables, so use those.

```
SELECT m.Gender, c.mID, m.mID
FROM [Circulation Info] AS c INNER JOIN Membership AS m ON c.mID = m.mID
GROUP BY m.mID
HAVING m.Gender='F'
```

Comment: I received a message saying that the I tried to executed query that does not include the specified expression 'Gender' as a part of an aggregate function

Comment: To avoid this error you should include m.Gender to GROUP BY or apply some aggregate function on m.Gender. Can you, please, explain what kind of output do you want to get?